# remove last item from array and rerender in react failed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I want to remove last item from array and rerender but I seem can't get it to work without using filter. But in my case I don't think filter is needed because I will always take away last item hence I use pop()

```
const CustomInput = (): JSX.Element => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState<string>("");
  const [items, setitems] = useState<string[]>(['1', '2']);

  const handleKeyDown = (e: any) => {

    if (items.length && e.keyCode === 8 && inputValue === "") {
      const newitems = items;
      newitems.pop();

      /* what is wrong here */
      console.log('newitems', newitems)

      setitems(newitems);
    }
  };

  const handleChange = (e: React.SyntheticEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const target = e.target as HTMLInputElement;
    setInputValue(target.value);
  };


  return (
    <div>
      {items.map((oo, index) => (
        <div >
          <span>
            {oo}
          </span>
        </div>
      ))}
      <input
        autoFocus
        type="text"
        value={inputValue}
        onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-hxzcpt

What's wrong?

Comment: Did you try initialising newItems as `const newitems = [...items];`
I think the problem that you are mutating your state value which results into react not knowing when to update it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[array::slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

You are mutating and saving the same state array reference back into state, which react sees as a "non-op", i.e. the array reference is the same so it bails on re-rendering it. You can use `slice` to copy the 0th through second to last elements into a new array reference, basically slicing "off" the last element each callback invocation.

```
const handleKeyDown = (e: any) => {

  if (items.length && e.keyCode === 8 && inputValue === "") {
    setitems(items.slice(0, -1)); // index 0 to last - 1
  }
};
```

Comment: very clean, but is it possible to replace it with es6? slice feel 'old' to me, hmm..

Comment: @AndreThonas I'm not quite sure I understand this question as array::slice is still part of the standard and there wasn't much added for arrays in [es6](http://es6-features.org/#FailSoftDestructuring) other than enabling a spread syntax for iterables. As you've seen though, spreading the current state into an array *and then* popping off the last element is actually more verbose. Just because `slice` is likely as old as the language itself (and not new and shiny) doesn't mean it isn't useful.

Answer (score 2):

You are mutating state directly.
here is a solution.

```
const newitems = [...items];
newitems.pop();
```

Comment: how is this removing the last item?

Comment: This doesn't remove the last item. You still need `.pop` to remove last item.

Comment: can you post full answer? I'm confused.

Comment: Edited. So your original code changes the state value directly which is not allowed in React.JS. you might use spread operator to create a new array and update state with it.

Comment: I'm assigning to a new variable, why do I need to spread here? hmm

Comment: Check [this](https://medium.com/@kkranthi438/dont-mutate-state-in-react-6b25d5e06f42)